# Condition for positive Determinant

Tags: matrices, determinant

If we have that for any non-zero vector $x$ that $Ax\cdot x$ is a positive, why is determinant of $A$ positive?

Comment: What have you tried?  What did your textbook say?

Comment: Do you know what eigenvalues and eigenvectors are?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Proof for the complex case (where the hypothesis applies to any non-zero vector, real or complex): the determinant is the product of the eigen values. If $\lambda$ is an eigen value then there exists a non-zero vector $x$ such that $Ax=\lambda x$ This gives $Ax.x=\lambda \|x\|^{2}$. LHS is positive by hypothesis and $\|x\|^{2}>0$. Hence $\lambda >0$. Hence determinant of $A$ is a product of positive numbers.

Real case: if $A$ is  a real matrix then eigen values can only occur in pairs $\lambda, \overline {\lambda}$ and the product of these is $|\lambda|^{2}$. Hence it is enough to see that the product of real eigen values is positive which follows by above argument since any eigen vector leads to a real eigen vector by taking real parts of its components.

Comment: What if $A$ is not diagonalizable?

Comment: I did not use the fact that $A$ is diagonalizable. Determinant is  the product of the eigen values for any square matrix. @DanielSchepler

Comment: What if $A$ is a real matrix, and you are using the real dot product and restrict $x$ to real vectors?  Then $A$ could have complex eigenvalues.

Comment: Not with the given hypothesis. If $Ax.x$ is real and positive for every non-zero vector $x$ then every eigen value is necessarily positive as I have shown.

Comment: Example: if $A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ -1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ then $Ax . x > 0$ for all nonzero real vectors $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$ but $A$ has eigenvalues $1 \pm i$.